# How to read parquet data with partitions from Aws S3 using presto?

Tags: amazon-s3, partitioning, parquet, presto

I have data stored in **S3** in form of **parquet files with partitions**. I am trying to read this data using **presto**. I am able to read data if I give the complete location of parquet file with partition. Below is the query to read data from "section a":

```
presto> create table IF NOT EXISTS default.sample(name varchar(255), age varchar(255), section varchar(255)) WITH (external_location = 's3://bucket/presto/section=a', format = 'PARQUET');
```

But my data is partitioned with different sections i.e. s3://bucket/presto folder contains multiple folders like "section=a", "section=b", etc.

I am trying to read the data with partitions as follows:

```
presto> create table IF NOT EXISTS default.sample(name varchar(255), age varchar(255), section varchar(255)) WITH (partitioned_by = ARRAY['section'], external_location = 's3://bucket/presto', format = 'PARQUET');
```

The table is being created but when I try to select the data the table is empty.

I am new to Presto, please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You create table correctly:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS default.sample(name varchar(255), age varchar(255), section varchar(255))
WITH (partitioned_by = ARRAY['section'], external_location = 's3://bucket/presto', format = 'PARQUET');
```

However, in "Hive table format" the partitions are not auto-discovered. Instead, they need to be declared explicitly. There are some reasons for this:

- explicit declaration of partitions allows you to publish a partition "atomically", once you're done writing
- `section=a`, `section=b` is only the convention, the partition location may be different. In fact the partition can be located in some other S3 bucket, or different storage

To auto-discover partitions in the case like yours, you can use the [`system.sync_partition_metadata` procedure](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#procedures) that comes with Presto.

Comment: Is the sync_partition_metadata procedure used to add partitions to the Hive metastore for a new table where those partitions already exist in S3? Or do they need to be added to the metastore directly? Asking as the procedure seems to have no effect in my system (v324 & Minio).

Comment: Yes, this should register partitions in metastore if the partitions exist in the file system. @kermatt a good place for troubleshooting is the `#troubleshooting` channel on Presto Community Slack https://prestosql.io/slack.html

Comment: is it a requirement to create a table? Is it possible to just read the parquet files from s3 without having to create a table?